# Video playback camera module connected to Raspberry Pi's GPIO

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I have a FLIR Lepoton camera module connected to my Raspberry Pi 3B+ board. Although I'm able to start it using this program ([Lepton Module - Raspberry Pi video](https://github.com/groupgets/LeptonModule/tree/master/software/raspberrypi_video)), when I'm trying to run another program which uses the numbers 0 or 1 as params for the onboard or USB camera, I got an error that the camera is not found, saying

> Cannot identify device '/dev/video1

Any idea how could I find where is it actually connected?